# Availability of dataset from "Loophole-free Bell inequality violation using electron spins separated by 1.3 kilometres"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, bells-inequality, data

I am looking for the most-raw data from the (in)famous [Loophole-free Bell inequality violation using electron spins separated by 1.3 kilometres](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature15759) experiment. I would like to try repeating their calculations, and possibly try some other statistical methods. I have searched their [supplmentary information](https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1038%2Fnature15759/MediaObjects/41586_2015_BFnature15759_MOESM113_ESM.pdf) for usages of the term "data" and didn't find any mention of whether or if such data is available in the surrounding paragraphs.

Is their dataset available anywhere?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe emailing the authors is a possibility?

Comment: @MaximalIdeal Thank you for the suggestion. I was hoping it was already available somewhere, but perhaps not. I have sent them an email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I emailed the authors of the original paper and they told me how to find the data set. They told me the data is publicly available at the following link:

https://data.4tu.nl/articles/dataset/Loophole-free_Bell-inequality_violation_using_electron_spins_separated_by_1_3_kilometres/12703235/1

It contains the following files:

- `bell_open_data.txt`
- `bell_open_data_analysis_example.py`
- `bell_open_data_header.ods`
- `bell_open_data_readme.rtf`

The pertinant data is contained in `bell_open_data.txt` however reading the README `bell_open_data_readme.rtf` gives a big-picture description and `bell_open_data_header.ods` gives some basic information about each column found in `bell_open_data.txt`.

It is worth looking inside `bell_open_data_analysis_example.py` to get concrete details of how the data was processed and how figures were prepared. It appears to have been written in Python 2.

As you mentioned, in their [supplementary](https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1038%2Fnature15759/MediaObjects/41586_2015_BFnature15759_MOESM113_ESM.pdf) information they describe how the data was processed. How you analyze the data using other methods is up to you.

---

As I learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74091070/download-data-zip-programmatically-for-loophole-free-bell-inequality-violation), you can download it using the following Python code:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://data.4tu.nl/ndownloader/files/24056582")

with open("data.zip", "wb") as f_out:
    f_out.write(r.content)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: However, when I attempt to download the data I get "500 Internal Server Error: nginx" with no downloaded files. I have contacted researchdata@4tu.nl to inquire about this.

Comment: Just a moment ago I tried to download the data and it worked this time. I have not heard back from researchdata@4tu.nl.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/1fcbc467b9387265b96944ba294d996b) is a Python gist which prepares a Pandas dataframe for further analysis.